Response Twice: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
i will make this problme easy to understand.This means that the req that is comming from client to you server, and the res that is being sended by server is twice, Means that the server is sending the res 2 time on client single req.
Example: code
As you can se i a getting  get req from client.
router.get("/:id", isUserAuthenticated, getUser); there is one middeleware and the second one is the function.
middeleware: isUserAuthenticated
what i am doing in this fn, is that i am checking if the user is authenticated or not if authenticated then just call next, if not the return res. The error occurs from here if i don't put the return in res then, what will happen it will send the request and move to the second fn because of next(), that's how express middleware work,if one is ture the move to next call stack fn, so i need to put a return so that it would not go to the second fn
export function isUserAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
return res.json(new ApiResponse(401, "Unathorized", false, null));
}

next();
}

the ans is simple just check, where you are returing res twice.
